# Enqueue and run jobs in Sidekiq from two Rails servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I have two servers: web server (front-end) and analytic (backend) server. I need to pass a job from front-end server to back-end server through Sidekiq.

My hack is:

1. Install Sidekiq in both web server and backend server. I now have front-end Sidekiq and back-end Sidekiq.
2. Configure front-end Sidekiq so that it points to Redis server of the back-end Sidekiq. In other words, two Sidekiq shares the same Redis database server.

Now, I need to enqueue a job from front-end Sidekiq, then execute a code from back-end Sidekiq.

How I should go about doing it?

Comment: This does not answer directly your question, so I post it as comment. Having multiple apps sharing the same db (especially in write mode) is often a bad idea, as it will lead soon or later to unpredictable and unreproducible race conditions and dependencies nightmare. Can't you just set up an API on backend app that frontend app calls to enqueue tasks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidekiq is a distributed messaging queue, and the whole purpose of it is for use cases like you described. Just setup a queue for the front-end to read, and a queue for the back-end to read. When you read it from the front-end queue, insert it back to the back-end queue.

Comment: Can I have multiple machines running the back-end Sidekiq - trying to scale horizontally ?